# CODEVITA "similar char" how to reduce my time complexity in c?

Tags: c, algorithm, time-complexity

Example 1

Input

9

abacsddaa

2

9

3

Output

3

1

Explanation

Here Q = 2

For P=9, character at 9th location is 'a'. Number of occurrences of 'a' before P i.e., 9 is three.

Similarly for P=3, 3rd character is 'a'. Number of occurrences of 'a' before P. i.e., 3 is one.

My answer is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int occ(int a,char *p){
  int cnt=0;
  for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
    if(p[i]==p[a]){
      cnt++;
    }
  }

  return cnt;
}

int main(){
  int l,q;

  scanf("%d",&l);
  char s[l];
  scanf("\n%s\n%d",s,&q);
  while(q>0){
    int n;
    scanf("\n%d",&n);
    n=n-1;
    int r=occ(n,s);
    printf("%d\n",r);
    q--;
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is working code and you want improvement suggestions then [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate site for this question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a C expert, but I can give you an idea of how to improve your time complexity in here.

You can use some sort of memorization, first ask: Is there any useful information I can get from iterating the array only once so I can answer each query faster?

Right now your solution do not pre process anything, and your complexity is O(n) per query. Let's make it something better, let's preprocess data in O(n) and answer each query in O(1).

You would have a map of characters that would count how many times a character appears. Notice that for index i, you just take into account appearances of s[i] before, so index i doesn't care about other characters.

Follow this approach

1. Create a vector(int) v of size s.length.
2. Create a map(char to int) m for counting characters appearances.
3. For i = 0 until s.length do:

   ```
    v[i] = m[s[i]]++
   ```

That way, you just calculated the answer for each index in one iteration.

Now, for each query q, just print v[q - 1].

Time complexity per query: O(1)

Extra space complexity: O(n)

Note: For better understanding of the whole answer, n is the length of the string (s.length)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: here i think insted of v[q-1], it should be v[q]-1. As v[q] will have frequency of a particular character till that index and we want before that index.

Comment: @Nitin Singhal, I don't think so, that's why it's m[v[i]]++, which first assigns the value and then increases the value. If it was ++m[v[i]] then yeah, it would happen what you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Current execution complexity is **O(lq)** while *l* is the length of the input array and *q* is the number of queries.

The complexity of each query is **O(l)**.

With proper data structure, you can store the input data in such way that each query will be **O(1)**. For example, you can create a table where each line will present the letter (from `a` to `z`, for this example let's assume we get only lower case letters). Each column will present the number of times, the given letter has occurred till (and including) the index of this column.

For instance if the input is `aabz`, the table will look like this:

```
   | 0    1    2    3
------------------------
 a | 1    2    2    2
 b | 0    0    1    1
 . | .    .    .    .
 . | .    .    .    .
 y | 0    0    0    0
 z | 0    0    0    1
```

In such case if you need to check number of occurrence of the letter at index 2 till (and including) this index, all you need to do is

1. Check the letter at index 2 in the input string (`'b'`)
2. Check the value in the lookup table at [`'b'`][2] --> 1

The complexity to create such table is **O(l)**. Here is an example for the code to build such table:

```
#define CHARS_SIZE ('z' - 'a' + 1)

// 'arr' - is the input array of chars
// 'len' - length of the input array
// 'lookup' - pointer to a zeroed (cleared) array of size: CHARS_SIZE * len * sizeof(*lookup)
void build_lookup(const char *arr, int len, int *lookup)
{
    int char_val;

    // normalize the letter to integer value between 0 (for 'a') and 25 (for 'z')
    char_val = arr[0] - 'a';
    lookup[char_val*len] = 1;

    // 'i' indicates the column index in the table
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i)
    {
        char_val = arr[i] - 'a';
        // update the number of occurrences for each letter a..z at column 'i'
        for (int char_iter = 0; char_iter < CHARS_SIZE; ++char_iter)
        {
            if (char_iter != char_val)
            {
                // same value as the previous one
                lookup[char_iter*len + i] = lookup[char_iter*len + i - 1];
            }
            else {
                // +1 to the value in the previous value
                lookup[char_iter*len + i] = lookup[char_iter*len + i - 1] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query, in such case, would be:

```
int occ(const char *arr, int len, const int *lookup, int idx){
    // normalize the letter to integer value between 0 (for 'a') and 25 (for 'z')
    int char_val = arr[idx] - 'a';

    return lookup[char_val * len + idx];
}
```

Here is your code with few additions of what I explained above: https://godbolt.org/z/zaY4RL

Note that I haven't tested it so there probably a few bugs so use it as a reference and not as a full solution.

Comment: thank u..i am preparing for codevita..u saved my lyf